# C# WPF - Owned windows don't properly get minimized

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I am in the process of writing a WPF application and I have 3 windows A, B and C. A owns B and B owns C (through setting the `Window.Owner` property).

Expected behavior:

- When B is minimized C also gets minimized. (Works as expected)
- When A is minimized B also gets minimized. (Works as expected)
- When A is minimized C also gets minimized. (Does not work as expected)

The issue arises when window C is active. If A is minimized while C is active, B also gets minimized but C does not. Otherwise it works properly.

I am minimizing window A programmatically by setting `WindowA.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized`. And at first glance this seems to minimize its owned window B but B's `StateChanged` event does not fire. This consequently stops me from manually minimizing window C by handling it in window B's `StateChanged` event.

I am currently at a loss as to what I should do to achieve the desired behavior.

I tried messing about with the windows' `ResizeMode` property by setting both window B and C's to `ResizeMode.CanMinimize`, however the same erroneous behavior persisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

I have found out that when a WPF window gets minimized instead of minimizing its child windows, it sets their `Visibility` to false instead. This was rather confusing because this is not stated in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.owner?view=windowsdesktop-8.0).

I mitigated the problem I faced by subscribing to window B's `IsVisibleChanged` event and setting window C's visibility to be equal to window B's.

```
windowB.IsVisibleChanged += delegate
{
  windowC.Visibility = windowB.Visibility;
};
```